# Rendering Problems: Android Studio 2.2 - Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, constraints

I am trying to use Constraint Layout in Android Studio 2.2.

I have installed **Android 2.2 studio**

I have added the latest Constraint Layout lib in apps gradle and build successfully.

**compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'**

Now when I try to drag and drop the widgets from the palette to android layout editor, It is not rending to editor and showing the following error.

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/constraint/R$styleable
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.(ConstraintLayout.java:1180)**

Here I am adding the snapshot for the same for better understanding.

what else I am missing here. please help.

**Additional Information:**

1.Windows 7 OS

2.64 Bit

Build.gradle:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "meterial.example.com.floatingactionbutton"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the project? or restart Android Studio? It may help sometimes.

Comment: Yes I did it many times .Even I have restarted my system but no use.

Comment: I have the same problem even with com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]Add new gradle dependency of constraint-layout

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'  
}
```

and rebuild the project.

Comment: Have you ever used  this version ?

Comment: Yes It is not released yet :)

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
is the current latest version

Comment: first please check and comment it and current latest version is alpha9

Comment: Hi Kiran,

Thank you so much. 
After adding "alpha9" support lib for constraint-layout issue get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have no Relative / Linear or any other element in your layout file . As I am seeing in your component tree (bottom left corner) empty .  The solution is first add any root element either `Relative/Linear`  layout . Then you can see the  the root element in you component tree (bottom left corner)  . After right clicking on in you will find a option to convert it to `constraint layout` . Then a pop up window might appear , check both and click `OK` then you can use constraint layout . Let me know if it works

[image]

Comment: Hi shuvro, As instructed...I have added a relative layout and converted into constraint layout. It didn't work.

Comment: what is your compileSdk version ?

Comment: Edited the question and added build.gradle.

Comment: did you try clean and rebuild ?

Comment: Yes, I did clean.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to download the repository for constraint before you use it, i got the same error as you have.

So open the Android Studio and Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK Tools and expand the Support Repository and click both ConstraintLayout for Android and Solver for ConstraintLayout and apply it'll start downloading.

After that paste the code below to build.gradle(Module:app) file dependencies block. and then go to Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files, to sync project.

`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'`

[Click to see where to insert the above line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVe56.png)

Refer [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) to do entire setup:

Answer (score 0):

Let Android Studio do everything for you - actually this is the purpose `ConstraintLayout` was created for.

So the clear algorithm to import and use `ConstraintLayout` looks like this.

1. Create new layout file -> switch to *Design tab* -> *Component tree* -> Right button click -> *Convert layout to `ConstraintLayout`* -> OK.

[image]

2. Rendering problem error appears in newly converted `ConstraintLayout` only if it's first `ConstraintLayout` in your project. In the case Android Studio will ask you to import `constraint-layout` library. Agree with that.

[image]

3. Here you go - rendering problems warning appears. But if you'll read its suggestions, you'll find the proposition to **build** the project. Just click build reference in the warning. If warning haven't disappeared, press **refresh** reference - this might be helpful in 99% cases.

[image]

This is the instruction for newly created file. If you try to convert to `ConstraintLayout` existing file, there are plenty of reasons to warn you about rendering problems. Mostly this happens when you use your own custom widgets, or views from `support` library, for instance try to wrap something in `CardView`.